# reveal fake number / prevent fake registration / fake sms

Tags: database, security, backend, user-registration, mobile-development

I faced with a such question for which can not find an answer in google. For example, I have a company which provides some services for customers. And for new users I have a promo/discounts. As we know there are a lot of websites which provide fake number for receiving sms for registration. I need a useful solution to prevent registration with such numbers. I want to check if this number is real or not and allow registration only if real. What is your suggestion/solution ? What would you do or maybe already did something for escaping a such problems.

Note:  Maybe Some tags are not relevant to this issue, so please inform me and I will remove this tag. Or vice verse, if you have any suggestions related tags please let me know I will add this tag.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but I think there are two kinds of SIM cards, physical and virtual, and I *think* you can tell somehow whether the number you received an sms from is assigned to a virtual sim (I guess through some kind of an API). However, some online sms providers use physical sim cards (sometimes for a different price), I don't think you can securely filter those, because I as a provider can just go to a telco and buy 20 sim cards for my customers to use, those will be very much the same as if I as a person bought them.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what you do is you take the number/email and you send it to a service most likely through an API. There is rarely any inhouse software that does this functionality!

Here are a few services, I have used & worked with etumos before, not bad but it comes with a price!

- https://etumos.com/products/etumos-verify/
- https://numverify.com/documentation

For numverify, it is free to an extent. Try it out & see if it works with your solution.

It supports **Carrier Detection**

> While phone numbers help businesses identify and legitimize customers, some numbers are very easy to retrieve from certain carriers. For exmaple, anyone can quickly register multiple phone numbers from a free online provider, making it easy to create fake profiles.
>
> To address this risk, the numverify API will return a separate `carrier` object containing the name of the carrier the requested phone number is registered with. This way businesses can require additional identity authentication for carriers associated with higher fraud instances.

Comment: How would you know if the number is assigned to a person, or an online sms number provider that anybody can register to? I can't see this in the numverify response.

Comment: @GaborLengyel , under Carrier Detection > "While phone numbers help businesses identify and legitimize customers, some numbers are very easy to retrieve from certain carriers. For exmaple, anyone can quickly register multiple phone numbers from a free online provider, making it easy to create fake profiles. To address this risk, the numverify API will return a separate carrier object containing the name of the carrier the requested phone number is registered with. This way businesses can require additional identity authentication for carriers associated with higher fraud instances."

Comment: Does that mean that I as the user of these services should still maintain the list of high risk carriers? Also is a carrier not something like Deutsche Telekom? Would that be different for an online sms provider? Might be dumb questions, just trying to learn something new. :)

Comment: Hmm, definitely maintaining a 'blacklist' will be done by the end-user. You wouldn't want to contact support every time to unblock or block something. Hence the carrier object will be returned by the API to the user for the user to process and sift out! The question is not dumb, everyone is here to learn! Read my bio! :)

Comment: http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=e958dd6d7c04ea741c7c5d564346ad5a&number=994556634613&country_code=&format=1

http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=e958dd6d7c04ea741c7c5d564346ad5a&number=447532696552&country_code=&format=1


There are 2 responses. One of them is my number other is fake. How can you realize which one is real.

Comment: Identifying whether the number is fake or not depends primarily on whether the carrier is trustable or not, the "valid:true" attribute can also be used as a first check. There are online sites that gives out temporary numbers, try those numbers, and see what carrier comes back.

Comment: I have seen your edits, yeah further analysis needs to be done on the Carrier to determine. It should act as a rough gauge.

Comment: @mallocation actually this number was taken from online site which provide fake numbers to receive sms from, mainly, registration. 
Even if this is not a right answer, generally thank you for attention and information, this site may be useful for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Send an SMS to the number, ask a question that a human can answer better than a bot and request a response.